# How to get the updated records in django

Tags: django

I have a table with some records in it.I also have an option to update these records.In another table I need the names of the fields which are updated for further use.

Comment: Django manipulates data through the models? Show your models to begin with?

Comment: `I also have an option to update these records`. Provide code for this also. So you know which fields are going to update. Then it's simple to pass the same fields to another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. I just used changed_data to get the list.